# Dynamic click event isn't firing in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, dynamic, controls

I am working on populating a PlaceHolder in a page with data from a SQLDataReader.  I can get all the data from the database, but when I attempt to add a click event to a dynamic linkbutton, the even won't fire.  I have tried putting the code in the PreInit and Init functions, but not a bite.  Thanks a lot!

Here's my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   InsertRotatorIntoSQL selectGroups = new InsertRotatorIntoSQL();
   SqlConnection conn = selectGroups.Connection();
   string groupCmd = "SELECT g.GroupID, g.GroupName, g.GroupDescription, i.ImgName FROM dbo.ImageGalleryGroups g INNER JOIN dbo.ImageGalleryImages i on i.GroupID=g.GroupID WHERE i.IsThumbnail=1";

   SqlCommand getGroupCmd = new SqlCommand(groupCmd, conn);
   conn.Open();

   SqlDataReader sdr = getGroupCmd.ExecuteReader();

   while (sdr.Read())
   {
        string id = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
        string name = sdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
        string desc = sdr.GetValue(2).ToString();
        string img = sdr.GetValue(3).ToString();
        Literal containerDiv = new Literal();
        containerDiv.Text = "<div style='float:left; margin:0 5px;'>";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(containerDiv);

        Literal t = new Literal();
        t.Text = "<h3>" + name + "</h3>";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(t);

        Image gThumb = new Image();
        gThumb.Width = 150;
        //todo implement css  border:1px solid #eee; padding:2px;
        gThumb.ImageUrl = "/App_Templates/Skin_1/ImageGalleryGroups/" + name + "/" + img;
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(gThumb);

        Literal br = new Literal();
        br.Text = "<br /><p> ";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(br);

        LinkButton del = new LinkButton();
        del.Click += new EventHandler(this.Delete_Group);
        del.Text = "Delete";
        del.CssClass = "delbtn";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(del);

        Literal d = new Literal();
        //create editgroup
        d.Text = " | <a href='ViewGroup.aspx?GroupID=" + id + "'>Edit</a></p>";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(d);

        Literal cdClose = new Literal();
        cdClose.Text = "</div>";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(cdClose);         
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your Delete_Group event handler to the code?

Comment: Sure.  It is just redirecting to a page at this point:     private void Delete_Group(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Thankyou.aspx");
    }

Comment: Try setting the ID of the LinkButton, del.ID = ...

Comment: Negative.  I still am getting the same result.  Maybe I should change the EventHandler call to a RoutedEventHandler?

Comment: Nope.  OnLoad didn't do it either.

Comment: Do yourself a favor before you run into serious scalability problems - bone up on 'using' and the IDisposable pattern. You're not cleaning up any of your database objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out of line and ask, is the code here just a little bit different from the one on your live server? The problem that you are describing usually comes up when you attach the click handles inside a `!IsPostBack` section.

In that case, while the postback is still caused when clicking the button, when control reaches end of Page_Load after the postback, the control does not have an associated click event and therefore, the event is never executed.
Could that be happening over here?

Comment: Nope.  That is the code that is running on the server.  It is for an AspDotNetStorefront site - could that be a hangup?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not really a fix, but a workaround I discovered:  I changed the LinkButton call to a plain Button, which worked out.  Not sure why, but it is a way forward at this point.  Thanks for your help!